# NOT_NULL contraint failed when adding foreign key to model in django

Tags: python, django

I am making a notes app. When I try to create a foreign key to link the user and its notes, im getting an error while using

```
python manage.py migrate
```

. I am very new to foreign keys, I looked at the Django docs, this is how they created a foreign key.

here's the code :

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)



class Note(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.body[0:50]
```

here's the error :

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__api_note.author_id
```

Comment: You need to update your migration to supply a default value for the author id of existing notes

Comment: I'm assuming you get this error when running `python manage.py migrate` if not please edit your question to include when you get the error

Comment: what does that mean? can you explain in simpler terms? I am completely new to Django.

Comment: Did you make migrations?

Comment: yep, I did make migrations.

Comment: And if you then attempt to apply those migrations you get this error?

Comment: yes, even after I do python manage.py makemigrations I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that that there are existing notes in the database that do not have a `author_id` field, but you have not set a default value and neither allowed to to be kept blank. Thus it's a `IntegrityError` to add the field.

You can solve this in 2 ways:

### Allow the field to be blank

1. Delete the last migration in your migrations folder
2. Edit the author field like this:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

3. Run makemigrations and migrate

### Set a default value for the field

1. Delete the last migration from the migrations folder. You can also edit it but simply deleting it is easiest
2. Run makemigrations again
3. During make migration, it will prompt you if you want to provide a default value for the field. Select "Provie a one of value for now"
4. Type `models.User.objects.all().first()` or alternatively some other "defalt" author for existing notes
5. Run `migrate`

You can also solve the problem by removing all existing notes from the database

Comment: from what I understood from your explanation, deleting the database's contents should also solve it right?

Comment: Yes, that would work too

Comment: I want to sort of start from scratch, how do I delete the database?

Comment: What type of database are you using? Postgres/SQLite/MySQL?

Comment: I have figured out how to delete the database, thanks for your explanation, it helped me a lot!